# Breaking Lines in PDF whose value is from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I'm trying to find a solution for my PDF problem. I'm inserting a value into my PDF from mysql database but the problem is that the value is going over the cells instead of breaking line.

Here's snippet:

```
include 'restaurantconnect.php';
$count=0;
$sql="SELECT * FROM `restaurant`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
 while($inventory = $result->fetch_assoc()){

 $concat = $inventory['first_name'] . " " . $inventory['last_name'];      

 $pdf->Cell(25,5,"{$inventory['food_id']}",1,0,"R");
 $pdf->Cell(50,5,"{$concat}",1,0,"C");
 $pdf->Cell(20,5,"{$inventory['package']}",1,0,"L");
 $pdf->Cell(100,5,"{$inventory['orders']}",1,0,"L");
 $pdf->Cell(70,5,"{$inventory['addons']}",1,1,"L");
```

The values on my **orders** are from mysql database which has

`rice,pork,seafood,vegetables, desserts`

What it shows in the pdf is like this

```
   food_id | concat | package | orders | addons
      1    | John   |   1     | rice, seafood vegetables, desserts | extras
```

What I want to happen is

```
   food_id | concat | package | orders | addons
      1    | John   |   1     | rice,se| extra
                               afood,ve
                               getables
```

Comment: Which PDF library are you using? The `Cell()` function smells like `FPDF`, it's been a while since I worked with it but I seem to recall that you need to use `MultiCell()` to support line breaks.

Comment: I'm using FPDF yes.